# Setting cookie in LiftFilter

Tags: google-app-engine, scala, lift

How do I set a cookie in a LiftFilter.doFilter method?

I tried to set the cookie as follows (stripped some code):

```
class AuthenticationFilter extends LiftFilter {

  override def  doFilter(request: ServletRequest, response: ServletResponse , chain: FilterChain) {

      val cookie = new HTTPCookie("SomeCookie", Full("" + System.nanoTime), Empty,
        Full("/authentication"), Full(60 * 60 * 24 * 14), Empty, Empty)
      cookie.setPath("/somePath")
      S.addCookie(cookie)

      val httpResp = response.asInstanceOf[HttpServletResponse]
      httpResp.sendRedirect("/some/page.html")

  }
}
```

However, when I check the browsers cookie, no cookie is set (apart from JSESSIONID), and I know the doFilter method is being executed because of logging messages and the fact that the browser is redirected to /some/page.html.

I'm using Scala 2.8, Lift 2.1-SNAPSHOT and the app is running is GAE (1.3.6, only tested on dev_appserver so far).

Any ideas? Thanks,

Gero

Comment: Already solved it by taking a different approach in which I do not need to set cookie in the filter. Did have a problem though to read the cookie in the filter using the S.cookieValue method. So instead I used request.asInstanceOf[HttpServletRequest].getCookies and then pick the right cookie. That worked... by may be can be improved.

Comment: I think your conversation with David Pollak provide interesting insights: http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb/browse_thread/thread/bce3211dc6a39349/af463c988448e592?show_docid=af463c988448e592&pli=1

Answer (score 1):

I posted the [same question to the Lift discussion list](http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb/browse_thread/thread/bce3211dc6a39349/af463c988448e592?show_docid=af463c988448e592&pli=1) and David Pollak pointed me in the right direction.

What I actually wanted to achieve was to be able to use a cookie value (if present) to retrieve some information of the user. There's no need to set a cookie for that in the filter, but the use of the LiftFilter in itself was in appropriate as David pointed out. You should not subclass the LiftFilter, but instead do the following in your Boot.scala:

```
LiftRules.statelessDispatchTable.prepend {
  case req if !checkReqForCookies(req) => () =>
    Full(RedirectResponse(whereTo, cookie1, cookie2))
}

def checkReqForCookies(in: Req): Boolean {
   ... do your checks ...
}
```

Works like a charm for me :-)